# C# "}" Error: Namespace definition, end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, namespaces

I cannot for the life of me find where my missing or extra "}" is, can anybody with fresh eyes point it out to me?! it is a very simple error that I cannot seem to figure out for myself. Also, if you see other errors that may be beneficial to fit, please let me know, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace NetchemiaWorksheet1
{

    private class Undergraduate 
    {

        // Initializing student information 
        private string StudentType;
        private string FirstName;
        private string LastName;
        private string Address;
        private long Phone;
        private long CafeteriaCredit;

        //Making private variables accesible
        private void SetString()
        {

            StudentType = "Undergraduate";
            FirstName = "Ian";
            LastName = "Lally";
            Address = "14512 S. Blackfoot Dr. Olathe, KS 66062";

        }

        public string GetString()
        {

            return StudentType;
            return FirstName;
            return LastName;
            return Address;

        }

        public void SetLong()
        {
            //Setting initial cafeteria credit to $0.00
            CafeteriaCredit =(long) 0.00;
            Phone = 9135155997;

        }

        public long GetLong()
        {

            return Phone;
            return CafeteriaCredit;

        }

    }

    private class Graduate
    {

        // Initializing student information
        private string StudentType;
        private string FirstName;
        private string LastName;
        private string Address;
        private long Phone;
        private long CafeteriaCredit;

        //Making private variables accesible
        private void SetString()
        {

            StudentType = "Graduate";
            FirstName = "Oscar";
            LastName = "Wilde";
            Address = "P. Sherman 42, Wallaby Way, Sydney Australia";

        }

        public string GetString()
        {

            return StudentType;
            return FirstName;
            return LastName;
            return Address;

        }

        public void SetLong()
        {

            CafeteriaCredit =(long) 0.00;
            Phone = 5557070707;

        }

        public long GetLong()
        {

            return Phone;
            return CafeteriaCredit;

        }

    }

    private class Doctorate
    {

        // Initializing student information
        private string StudentType;
        private string FirstName;
        private string LastName;
        private string Address;
        private long Phone;
        private long CafeteriaCredit;

        //Making private variables accesible
        private void SetString()
        {

            StudentType = "Doctorate";
            FirstName = "Albert";
            LastName = "Einstein";
            Address = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20500";

        }

        public string GetString()
        {

            return StudentType;
            return FirstName;
            return LastName;
            return Address;

        }

        public void SetLong()
        {

            CafeteriaCredit =(long) 0.00;
            Phone = 5551234567;

        }

        public long GetLong()
        {

            return Phone;
            return CafeteriaCredit;

        }

    }  

class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //initializing Classes
        Undergraduate IanLally = new Undergraduate();
        Graduate OscarWilde = new Graduate();
        Doctorate AlbertEinstein = new Doctorate();

        //Data members are inaccessible directly
        //Accessing through Methods within Class

        string U = IanLally.GetString();
        long UL = IanLally.GetLong();
        string G = OscarWilde.GetString();
        long GL = OscarWilde.GetLong();
        string D = AlbertEinstein.GetString();
        long DL = AlbertEinstein.GetLong();


            //Pulling Student Transcript
            public void Transcript(string StudentType) 
            {
                //Pseudo code
                Console.WriteLine("Retrieve" + StudentType + "Transcript");

            }

            //Enrolling in new course
            public void NewClass()
            {
                //Making array of classes available
                string[] Courses = new string[] {"ANTH 200", "BIOL 100", "PSYC 104", "ECON 144"};

                Console.WriteLine("Choose the courses in which you would like to enroll by entering the course acronym: ");

                //outputting Courses array
                foreach(var item in Courses) {

                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

                }

                //Pseudo code
                    Console.WriteLine("Course" + Courses[1] + "added.");

            }

            //Buying lunch credits
            public void Credit() 
            {

                    //pseudo code
                Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to add to your Cafeteria Credits?");
                Console.WriteLine("Amount now added to your credits.");

            }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I can't find the syntax error, but the mess of private classes and functions defined inside of functions is a *MAJOR* red-flag.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: Its really, really bad practice. Classes should (almost) always be marked as public, put your functions inside of them (instead of other functions). This makes it more unit testable, more maintainable, and way more readable. Fixing it may expose your other error as well.

Comment: You also have several functions with multiple consecutive return statements (which means the ones after the first wont be hit). You should be using properties to access your data. In general, this code just looks really bad.

Comment: *""14512 S. Blackfoot Dr. Olathe, KS 66062";"*... heh, thats right down the road from me. :)

Comment: Uh oh, now you know where I live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this fiddle that reproduces the error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eObBMs

The compiler is confused because it sees a method definition where it expects a closing bracket.

The issue is *not* that you are missing a bracket, but that you have methods defined within a method. You can't do that.

Pull the methods defined within `static void Main(string[] args)` out of the `Main` method.

Comment: Agreed.  `Program.Main()` has nested methods.  That doesn't work.

Comment: I remember reading about some way you actually *could* do that, but I could remember wrong. Regardless its ridiculoulsly bad practice and moving them will likely expose (if not fix) the problem. +1

Comment: There are also other legal, but useless things like having multiple return statements in `Doctorate.GetString()`

Comment: Okay! Thank you for your help! I am still a beginner programmer that is learning the ropes, so thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @user3002707 No worries. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if  it resolves your issue.

Comment: When I pull the methods in Main out of Main, should I place them in each class(Undergraduate, Graduate, and Doctorate)?

Comment: @user3002707 Well, you should place them wherever those methods are relevant. It's hard to say as your program/methods are still pretty abstract. As an exercise, think of it this way: what does a doctorate *do*? What does a graduate *do*? Think of verbs that might apply. That will help you define what kind of methods should be defined within that particular class. Your methods don't make a whole lot of sense, `Transcript` is a noun, not a verb. What action does `Transcript` describe? It doesn't really add up. Same with `Credit` and `NewClass`. `NewClass` sounds like it should be a constructor.